# Mikro-ORM w/MongoDB does not detect changes to arrays or insert new values

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mikro-orm

The problem I'm facing is that Mikro-ORM doesn't seem to detect array changes or be able to insert values into arrays. For example when inserting a number into a numbers array. I'm using MongoDB which natively supports arrays so it would be nice to work with them.

Down below is the Entity definition:

```
@Entity()
export class ProblemExample {
    @PrimaryKey()
    _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId()

    @Property()
    name: string = ""

    @Property({type: "json"})
    objectArray: {text: string}[] = []

    @Property({type: "array"})
    selectedNumbers: number[] = []
}
```

```
export async function appendNumber() {
    const em = await getEntityManager()
    let modifyExample = await em.findOne(ProblemExample, {_id: new ObjectId("645df88643fffa295e0421ff")})

    if (!modifyExample) { return }
    modifyExample.name += "modified"
    modifyExample.objectArray.push({text: "new Object"})
    modifyExample.selectedNumbers.push(randomInt(100))

    await em.flush()
}
```

When the code above runs the debugger outputs this:

```
[query] db.getCollection(‘ProblemExample’).find({ _id: ObjectId(‘645df88643fffa295e0421ff’) }, {}).limit(1).toArray(); [took 32 ms]
[query] db.getCollection(‘ProblemExample’).updateMany({ _id: ObjectId(‘645df88643fffa295e0421ff’) }, { ‘$set’: { name: ‘modified’ } }, {}); [took 38 ms]
```

But It does not update the array with the new number and the JSON array with the objects.
How do i make it update the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I solved using native update/insert/delete

```
em.nativeInsert<T extends AnyEntity>(entityName: string, data: any): Promise<IPrimaryKey>;
    em.nativeUpdate<T extends AnyEntity>(entityName: string, where: FilterQuery<T>, data: any): Promise<number>;
    em.nativeDelete<T extends AnyEntity>(entityName: string, where: FilterQuery<T> | any): Promise<number>;
```

You can find here the documentation
https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-mongo#native-collection-methods

This happen bacause .push not update the reference of array and I think mikro-orm check the reference before update a property about entity.